# Xam.Plugins.Settings by James Montemagno doesn't seem to save my settings

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use James Montemagno's settings plugin in a Xamarin forms app, but each time I restart my app, the settings go back to the defaults, not showing the changes I made to them during the last run of the app.

The AddOrUpdateValue and other methods have a filename parameter, which seems to be optional. Or is it required? I tried it with a filename, but it still doesn't seem to save the settings.

Is there something I need to do to "save" the settings? I must be missing something...

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. It was a stupid mistake on my part. I've been staring at the code for days and didn't see (until today) that I was passing not the key, but the setting itself as the first parameter to AddOrUpdateValue:

```cs
set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(MySetting, value);
```

instead of this:

```cs
set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(MySettingKey, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Save" for `Xam.Plugins.Settings`.

Here is an example using a static class:

```cs
using Plugin.Settings;
using Plugin.Settings.Abstractions;

public static class Settings 
{
    static ISettings AppSettings => CrossSettings.Current;

    public static string MySetting 
    {
        get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("MySettingKey", LastUsedDefault);
        set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("MySettingKey", value);
    }
}
```

And when you need to update or retrieve a setting, simply use it like any property:

```cs
var Foo = Settings.MySetting;
```

or

```cs
Settings.MySetting = Bar;
```

Comment: Thanks! the "MySettingsKEY" was the clue that opened my eyes, so to speak (see my answer).

Comment: Hi @user3573712! Please upvote and accept the answer (click the checkmark) to help devs who hit the same problem in the future!